# dependent variable One hot encoder

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am new to `machine learning` my question is:

> Do we need to encode **dependent variable** y if it contains *three class
>   segments 1,2,3* and I want to know if there is need to encode the
>   dependent variable when it contains no

Answer (score 0):

OneHotEncoder will create `k` number of columns if there are `k` classes for a single variable.

For example : it will create `2` variables if  gender values in that dataset are `Male/Female`,
It will create `3` Variables if gender values are `male/Female/PreferNotToSay`

Now, You don't want multiple variables in your predicate `y`, So better go with `LabelEncoder`(from sklearn.preprocessing) or some mechanism that keeps the dimensionality intact.

Answer (score 0):

I did not clearly get what dependent variable in your case.

1. If you are talking about 'y' the output, then no need of one hot encoding.
2. If a particular column is combination/dependent on any other columns. In machine learning, one column has some or other relation between another.
3. Better to do one hot encoding on categorical variables.

Below is an example of what one hot encoding does:

Before:

```
name gender
a     M
b     F
c     O
```

After

```
name M F O
a    1 0 0
b    0 1 0
c    0 0 1
```